# Javascript regex first character only specified set of characters

Tags: javascript, html

Please can someone help me with javascript regular expression for this

I133567 (first character with either letter I,S or A only in uppercase) and set of numbers.

Comment: What did you tried? Share your code and we will try to help you.

Comment: `/[ISA]\d+/` now please specify your real question..

Comment: @NikNik, this is what i tried `/^[ISA] [0-9]*$/, `

Comment: what i want is just to validate user input with first character an uppercase letter with either I,S or A only, then followed by any digit

Comment: @akinlex regex takes whitespace serious. its matching S 123 but not S123 as well as it would match "S "

Answer (score 0):

This will match them:

```
var pattern = /[ISA]\d+/g;
```

Don't know how many numbers you require on the end but as of now this will do infinitely many.

Comment: `{1}` is not required here. without it it will match exactly the same.

Comment: also throwing `^` and `$` into the regex when using `/g` and not even `/m` is kinda weird

Comment: `\d+` is greedy. it should match the whole number until the end except if you swap greedyness around. so `^` and `$` are not required